# php-ga: Using doubleclick.net for remarketing

Tags: php, google-analytics

Has someone used doubleclick.net with php-ga? It seems that it uses ga.js by default, but I'm new to it. This is what I am trying to use: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en

This is php-ga: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
$config = new GoogleAnalytics\Config();
$config->setEndPointHost('stats.g.doubleclick.net');
$this->tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker($ga_code, $url, $config);
```